# How to understand the result of argmax (uncommon array)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I encountered a problem when I was applying the `argmax` on an uncommon 3 dimensional array, just like in the code below:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([
    [
        [1, 5, 5, 2],
        [9, -6, 2, 8],
        [-3, 7, -9, 1]
    ],

    [
        [-1, 5, -5, 2],
        [9, 6, 2, 8],
        [3, 7, 9]
    ]
])
print('a, axis=0\n', np.argmax(a, axis=0))
print('a, axis=1\n', np.argmax(a, axis=1))
# print('a, axis=2\n', np.argmax(a, axis=2)) if this activated, Erros appears:numpy.AxisError: axis 2 is out of bounds for array of dimension 2.

b = np.array([
    [
        [1, 5, 5, 2],
        [9, -6, 2, 8],
        [-3, 7, -9, 1]
    ],

    [
        [-1, 5, -5, 2],
        [9, 6, 2, 8],
        [3, 7, 9, 9]
    ]
])
print('b, axis=0\n', np.argmax(b, axis=0))
print('b, axis=1\n', np.argmax(b, axis=1))
print('b, axis=2\n', np.argmax(b, axis=2))
```

Results:

```
a, axis=0

 [0 1 1]

a, axis=1

 [1 1]

b, axis=0

 [[0 0 0 0]

 [0 1 0 0]

 [1 0 1 1]]

b, axis=1

 [[1 2 0 1]

 [1 2 2 2]]

b, axis=2

 [[1 0 1]

 [1 0 2]]
```

For the results of array `b`, I totally understand its calculation rule, however, as for the array `a`, according to the errors, as far as I am concerned, it is not a real 3D array, but why can the function `argmax` still get its result? And how does the function get its result?

Comment: Have you tried printing `a`? It might give you a hint about what's going wrong.

Comment: `a` is a 2d object dtype array, containing lists.  The `max/argmax` functions work on object dtype by applying the `<>` comparisons to the elements.  As such it depends on how those are implemented by the objects themselves, `alist1 < alist2`.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, and is it intentional, that the only difference between `a` and `b` is that `b` has `[3, 7, 9,  9]` where `a` has `[3, 7, 9]`? Is this what you mean by "uncommon"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`B` is a 3d Array that Argmax knows how to naivgate and that's ok, but `A` is different as A is 2d array of `lists`.

When you say

```
print('a, axis=0\n', np.argmax(a, axis=0))
```

Argmax looks at your `A` as

```
[
[list11,list12,list13],
[list21,list22,list23]

]
```

so what it trys to do is get the max out of each of

`max(list11, list21) , max(list12,list22) , max(list13, list23)`

The problem here is that it relies on the `<,>,=`  operators implemented for lists which is implemented as follows

> The comparison uses lexicographical ordering: first the first two
>   items are compared, and if they differ this determines the outcome of
>   the comparison; if they are equal, the next two items are compared,
>   and so on, until either sequence is exhausted.

Example

```
[1,2,3] > [2,3,1] # False
[1111,2,3] > [2,3,1] # True
[1,2,3] > [1,3,1] # False comparing second elements
```

To get more intuition into this, let's try a tweak to your `A` array

```
a = np.array([ 
         [ 
             [1, 5, 5, 2], 
             [19, -6, 2, 18], 
             [-3, 7, -9, 1] 
         ], 

         [ 
             [-1, 5, -5, 2], 
             [9, 6, 2, 111118], 
             (-5555, 7, 9) 
         ] 
     ]) 
     print('a, axis=0\n', np.argmax(a, axis=0))
```

This will throw an error trying to compare a tuple with a list as there is no operator implemented for such comparison:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'list'
```

So in your case it compares the first element in each list and that's it, which makes the result look awkward and may be wrong for you.

If you have to do it like this then you may need to override those operators for the list to get the results you want, in other words implement your custom comparison operators for the list to compare those list properly.

You can read more about operator overloading in python, here is a basic example to start with:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operator-overloading